# Algorithms - O, Omega, Theta bounds

Tags: algorithm

f (n) = log(n + 5), g(n) = log(25n2).

The aim was to determine whether f(n) is O, o, Omega, small-omega, or theta of g(n).
This is the solution I saw somewhere:

By the logarithm rules and the summation rules we know that g(n) = log (25n2) = log ((5n)2) = 2 log (5n) = 2 log 5+2 log n = Θ(log n).
The final step is true because the summation rule tells us we can ignore the term 2 log 5 and the definition of Θ tells us we can ignore the 2 in front of log n. Next consider f (n) we know that for n > 5 we have log (n) < log (n + 5) = f (n) < **log (2n)**.
We know that log (2n) = log (2) + log (n) ≤ 2 log (n) by the summation rule. This implies that for n > 5, f (n) is less than 2 times log n which by the definition of big-O means that f (n) = O(log n). Similarly since log (n) < log (n + 5) = f(n) we have that f (n) = Ω(log (n)). Since f (n) is O( log n) and f (n) is Ω( log n) by the definition of Θ, we f (n) = Θ( log n). Since g(n) = Θ( log n) and f (n) = Θ( log n), this implies that g(n) = Θ(f (n)).

this is the solution.
What I don't understand from this solution is where did the f(n) = 2n come from (as bolded in the explanation above). Is that just a way to compare functions?
Please explain solution better.

Answer (score 0):

The author is just trying to show that *f(n) = Θ(log n)* by squeezing it in between *log n* and *log(2n)*, which are both *Θ(log n)*.

So *log(2n)* did not "come from" anywhere; the author just showed that since *f(n) < log(2n)* for sufficiently large *n*, then it is bounded above by *log(2n) = Θ(log n)*. It could have been shown in different ways too.